# How to manage configuration files in local and production enviorment in Laravel

Tags: php, git, laravel

I am using Git to manage code on my webserver. I write the code on local machine, push it to git hub and pull it form my server.

Configuration on my local machine and server are quite different.

The problem is how to configure git in such a way that it works both on server and local machine without need to manually changing the config files.

I know local and production env but the problem is in app.php config file, on local machine i need to load 'debugbar' where as on server i dont need to.

Comment: If you use debugbar "as is" (without any debugbar's commands / functions) just don't pull it with composer and thats it.

Comment: then i will get class not found error coz it is there in app.config

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding `debugbar`, you can do the following in `routes.php` or a `ServiceProvider`:

```
if(env('APP_ENV') != 'local') {
    Debugbar::disable();
}
```